# How to implement undo functionality?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, system-design

In my application I want to provide the user with a small undo functionality. There aren't many actions than can be undone by the user. Particularly the actions are:

- Add notes to an object
- Color an object
- Tag a objcet with a string

Now I thought about how to implement this. I first thought of a Action Class that is the abstract base class for the 3 different actions that can be taken by the user. Every time the user takes on of these actions, a new appropriate instance of a subclass of this abstract Action class is created and inserted into a list that contains all actions.

Whenever the user wants to undo something, the list is displayed to the user and he can choose which action he want to undo.

Now I was thinking what has to be stored in such an action object:

- the state of the object before the action
- the actual action that was taken (e.g. the string that was added to a object's notes)

I'm not sure if this is enough. I also thought about something like a chronological ordering, but this should be necessary since the list can be maintained chronologically correct.

Are there any other things I should consider?

Comment: Search for the memento pattern in GOF

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755/design-pattern-for-undo-engine

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Undo/redo is commonly implemented with the [Command Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx).  The `Action` class can be used as the basis for this, but you need a 'do' action and an 'undo' action within each command.  [Here is an example](http://mattberther.com/2004/09/16/using-the-command-pattern-for-undo-functionality) of this in practice.
You should probably store the commands executed in a stack as it makes it much easier to implement and much easier for the user to follow.

Answer (score 9):

You could do something simple like this:

```
Stack<Action> undoStack = new Stack<Action>();    

void ChangeColor(Color color)
{
    var original = this.Object.Color;
    undoStack.Push(() => this.Object.Color = original);
    this.Object.Color = color;
}
```

Comment: I like this one.  Had never thought of storing actual Actions...very nice.

Answer (score 5):

you should implement the **Command Pattern** for every action you want undo:

[how to implement undo/redo operation without major changes in program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973557/how-to-implement-undo-redo-operation-without-major-changes-in-program)

Answer (score 2):

For Correct and proven implememtation for UNDO functionality is Command Pattern

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to overlook this [Simple-Undo-redo-library-for-Csharp-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/456591/Simple-Undo-redo-library-for-Csharp-NET) when adding Undo/Redo functionality to existing projects.